# Mouse flickering in Chrome triple monitor setup on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, mouse, amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome

I recently added a new Radeon Cedar video card to my machine for a third monitor and whenever I have the third monitor enabled AND I'm using chrome AND the screen is repainting for a reason other then moving the mouse, the mouse flickers. So basically any action in chrome besides looking at a static page. It doesn't matter which monitor chrome is in and none of my other programs have this issue (as of yet)

I've looked through google and all the similar bug reports seem to be years old and resolved with a comment saying a fix was pushed (or not at all).

- OS: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04
- VC: Radeon Cedar

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration?  This is in Chrome settings, go to the bottom, click Advanced, and it's towards the bottom.  Just uncheck the box and restart Chrome.

Comment: @Dorian - That made it even worse, unfortunately. The cursor essentially disappeared.

Comment: Ok, re-enable the HA, then go here in the address bar: `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization` and select "Force-Enable for all layers".  See if that works.

Comment: @Dorian - That makes scrolling better. Which means that it only flickers an exceeding amount while some page is loading in the background.

Comment: Ok, well, progress at least.  But it if it only happens with Chrome, it's hard to tell if it's a Chome issue, or a driver issue.

Comment: @Dorian - I've been going through my other programs and I think it may be a driver thing since FF and sublime also have flicker. So I may need to close this question and open a new one with better information.

Comment: If that's the case then I agree with you.